# Why are there the gaps between shapes in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, rendering

I try to draw some rectangles side by side,but there is gap perhaps one pixel between the the rectangles.
it is better after I set rectangle's SnapsToDevicePixels =true or UseLayoutRounding = true,but after I resize the window,the gaps still occur.

Here is the code about drawing rectangle.

```
    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        DrawRectangle();
    }

    private void DrawRectangle()
    {
        var width = this.grid1.ActualWidth;
        var height = this.grid1.ActualHeight;
        var step = width / 15;
        this.grid1.Children.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
            rectangle.Width = step;
            rectangle.Height = height;
            rectangle.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            rectangle.Margin = new Thickness(i * step, 0, 0, 0);
            rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            rectangle.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
            //rectangle.UseLayoutRounding = true;
            this.grid1.Children.Add(rectangle);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why don't use a `StackPanel` as a container instead of a `Grid`? Then you can just add your rectangles without this `rectangle.Margin = new Thickness(i * step, 0, 0, 0);` setting trick...

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @nemesv Stackpanel is OK here,but actually I want to create rectangle more than one row.

Comment: -1... changing the requirements again, are you? Why don't you just edit your question to ask what you actually want instead of wasting time?

Comment: WrapPanel will give you rectangles on more than one row, and it has the benefits of StackPanel.

Answer (score 1):

How about setting the `Rectangle.Stroke` property to the same colour?:

```
rectangle.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
rectangle.StrokeThickness = 1.0;
```

UPDATE >>>

After you have now specified that you *actually* want multiple rows of `Rectangle` objects, all I can recommend is that you use a `WrapPanel` instead of your `Grid` control. You can achieve no joining lines using the following code in your loop:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
rectangle.Width = step;
rectangle.Height = height;
rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
rectangle.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
this.grid1.Children.Add(rectangle);
```

Comment: What about rectangles with different colors?

Comment: Had you specified this requirement in your question, then I would not have suggested this answer... this is why it really helps us users if question authors provide full details of what they actually want in their questions. Is this an actual requirement now?

Comment: Sorry about not making my question clear.I want to know why the gaps exists.